# I 'm trying to use this form to capture user details and load them in a MySQL table using the PHP script at the bottom, but it's not working

Tags: php

```
<div class="one_quarter">
    <h6 class="heading">Newsletter</h6>
    <p class="nospace btmspace-15">To receive regular updates subscribe to our mailing list</p>
    <form action="php/newsletter.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Newsletter:</legend>
            <input class="btmspace-15" type="text"  placeholder="Name">
            <input class="btmspace-15" type="text"  placeholder="Email">
            <textarea name="visitor" rows=4 cols=20></textarea>
            <button class="btn" name="button" type="submit" value="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The PHP script is like this:

```
<?php
require 'dbconf.php';
$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'visitor');
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $from)) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
        error_log("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        die('Internal server error');
    }
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'webapp_comment');
    if (!$db_select) {
        error_log("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        die('Internal server error');
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `webapp_comment.webapp_newsletter`(name,email,subscription_message) VALUES ('" . $first_name . "', '" . $from . "','" . $message . "')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        
        echo '<script>alert("Your comment has been received . We will contact you shortly");</script>';
        echo '<script>location.href = "../contact.html"</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

This should load the data into a table and pop-up a confirmation message which the users closes and get redirect to the "contact us" page.

The same PHP script works perfectly  with other forms that I have on the website, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong here. When I click submit it just loads a blank page at `www.example.com/contacts/php/newsletter.php` instead of popping up the confirmation message or loading the `www.example.com/contacts/contact.html` page.

Comment: Your inputs need the name attributes, i.e. name="email" and name="name" else your $_POST wont have those values. If you perform a var_dump($_POST) you have seen that.

Comment: You should realise that if you at least debug incoming data and rendered SQL query, Please, respect others and debug your code before writing questions at StackOverflow, we cannot do basic work for you. You can also use the browser inspector to check if valid payload is sent in POST request. It isn't in your case.

Comment: I take it that the comment is inserted, but the redirect doesn't work out?  Have you checked that the URL for redirection is correct?  Maybe "/contacts/contact.html" rather than requesting "../contact.html" (which makes it /php/contact.html rather than /contacts/contact.html)?

Comment: The redirect url is fine. Actually that part is optional. Sorry @biesior for feeling disrespected

Comment: You should really use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and injecting the user data into the queries like that. I also doubt that your `filter_input()`-function sufficient to protect you from SQL injections.

Comment: You say that you get a blank screen. If your query fails (if `$result` is falsy), you're not doing anything so that would result in a blank screen. Add some [error handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for your query and it might help you know what's going on. Just remember to never output error messages in production.

Answer (score -1):

You have several mistakes in your code, most important is wrong `name="button"` for submit button, while in PHP you're checking if `isset($_POST['submit'])`. Second thing is `if (isset($_POST['submit'], $from))`. Also as somebody mentioned use prepared statements for SQL, as I prefer PDO the sample uses it.

It works:

```php
<?php
require 'dbconf.php';
$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'visitor');
if (isset($_POST['submitme']) && isset($from)) {

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=webapp_comment;charset=utf8", $username, $password);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO webapp_newsletter (name, email, subscription_message) VALUES (?,?,?)");
    $result = $stmt->execute([$first_name, $from, $message]);

    if ($result) {
        echo '<script>alert("Your comment has been received . We will contact you shortly");</script>';
        echo '<script>location.href = "../contact.html"</script>';
    }
}
```

also remember about changed `name` for submit button.
Note, that's ***submetme*** because in some browsers using ***submit*** name conflicts with JS and should be avoided.

```html
<div class="one_quarter">
    <h6 class="heading">Newsletter</h6>
    <p class="nospace btmspace-15">To receive regular updates subscribe to our mailing list</p>
    <form action="pdo.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Newsletter:</legend>
            <input class="btmspace-15" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            <input class="btmspace-15" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            <textarea name="visitor" rows=4 cols=20></textarea>
            <button class="btn" name="submitme" type="submit" value="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Note that problems wasn't caused by your mysqli approach, but in wrong names and if conditions. Also, keep in mind that INSERT INTO doesn't require database prefix.

Comment: Any particular reason for downvoting this tested and valid solution?